Logout issue once the app has been uninstalled. (firebase)
In my flutter app I keep the user's status on firebase 'active' or 'inactive'. But I ran into this problem where if the user deletes the app without signing out the status remains active.
Is there a way to detect when the app is being uninstalled or any other solutions to change status?
Here's a snippet from my signout function where I change the status to inactive :
  FutureOr<void> _signOut(
      SettingsSignOutEvent event, Emitter<SettingsState> emit) async {
    // Get the current user's ID
    String? currentUserId = AuthenticationRepository().getCurrentUserId();

    if (currentUserId != null) {
      // Update user's status to "inactive" in Firestore
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .doc(currentUserId) // Update the document of the current user
          .update(
        {
          'status': 'inactive',
          'token': 'null',
        },
      );
    }
    AuthenticationRepository().signOut(context: event.context);
  }

Without the user signing out the status remains active even when the app is uninstalled.

There is no good way to be able to run some code when an app is uninstalled.  On top of that, trying to record the user's activity status like this is generally not a great idea.  There are two things to consider: 1) Being "signed in" using Firebase isn't a backend decision.  It just means the user has a valid user token on the device where they are signed in, and that token can last forever. 2) What would you do if the user downloads and signs in to the app on multiple devices (which is valid by design), and then signs out on just one of them?  Do they become "inactive" on the other device?

Also, what if the user discards or wipes their device entirely?  There is absolutely no way of knowing if either of those things happen.  Your database will contain confusing data.

User being active should not be derived from if he saved the token.
update firebase database when user is logged in,  when he/she closes or minimizes app, you can have AppLifecycleEventHandler implemented to listen onPause event, and update active status as disabled when users pauses the app. You can also impelment onResume method and update active status to active when user resumes the app.

@DougStevenson '2) What would you do if the user downloads and signs in to the app on multiple devices (which is valid by design), and then signs out on just one of them? Do they become "inactive" on the other device?' . I made it so that a user can only login when the status is inactive so a user cannot login on multiple devices . The reason for this was that I wanted to save only one device token per user.

What if the user signs in on one device, discards it, then tries to sign in on another device?  They will forever be unable to use the app correctly.  That's why this method of tracking the user is fundamentally flawed and will just cause problems in the long run.

@DougStevenson yes that's exactly the problem I'm facing. thank you for your comment I will take the advice and try a new approach to see if it resolves the issue.

At best, you can record the last time the user used the app on any device, but you can't realistically have a boolean value that says whether or not they are "active".
